# please help me with the my OOP PHP doubt?

Tags: php, oop, this

I have the foll prog

```
class Person {
  var $name;
  function Person () {

  }
}

$fred = new Person;
$fred->name = "Fred";
$barney =& new Person;
$barney->name = "Barney";

echo $barney->name;
echo $fred->name;
```

both the echo statements give the right same output ie "Fred" and "Barney" so whats the use of giving & while declaring $barney. what does "&" refer to here?

THanks

Comment: This is PHP4.  Why are you not using PHP5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [References Explained](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) in the PHP Manual.

Is there any particular reason why you are still using PHP4? It is no longer supported and PHP5s OOP is much more solid and capable.

Comment: You are probably learning from outdated material then. PHP4 is dead. Have a look at the chapters *Getting Started* and *Language Reference* in the PHP manual. The manual is actually pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

#### References in PHP4 (http://www.php.net/manual/en/oop4.newref.php)

It means 'by reference.' It becomes synonymous, rather than a copy of ([further reading](http://www.obdev.at/developers/articles/00002.html)). Also, the new way to write a constructor is not to use the same name as the class itself, instead, you use the `__construct()` function:

```
class Person {

  function __construct() {
    // setup shop
  }

}
```

Also, be sure to use [Visiblity](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) properly by assigning certain methods and properties as 'public,' 'private,' 'protected,' etc.

Comment: guess its ok if we dont write public as far as I know there is nothing like public private access types in PHP?

Comment: Yes, Nishant. There are public, private, protected in OOP in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

It passes the variable as a reference but this is no longer needed in PHP5+.